# ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "Steelpac Site" 26 (1.1.1.27). Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery: 
ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs . See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more information. 
After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application Loader to upload a new binary to App Store Connect. 
Best regards,
The App Store Team

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  Simply posting an error message is not sufficient.  You need to explain what you are doing and ask an actual question.

Comment: @Jason you think we can link this https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7323 while build creation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ITMS-90909: Deprecated API Usage with iOS in Xamarin Forms app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60136458/itms-90909-deprecated-api-usage-with-ios-in-xamarin-forms-app)

Answer (score -1):

UIWebView is still in the iOS13 betas, so probably have until iOS14.

Answer (score -2):

Apple UIWebView is only warning so this issue will be fixed after update code.

Please try:

1.Remove the Web View plugin:

cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview

2.Add Web View plugin:

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@latest

3.Please check "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" https://ionicframework.com/docs/faq/cors#server-headers-response-

Hope your problem will be fixed.