# ITMS-90909: Deprecated API Usage with iOS in Xamarin Forms app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Can anyone suggest what to do about this message that I get when submitting my Xamarin Forms app to the iOS store?

[image]

### Comment on possible duplicates

This question was asked before and not answered; I don't think an answered duplicate exists.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue which was recently closed by the Xamarin team issue can be found here https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7323

And the fix is and i qoute

> All the bits are in place, solution time! TL;DR: all is described in this piece of documentation here.
>
> Make sure you are using the latest Visual Studio (for Mac) on the stable channel, that should put you on the right path. At the moment, you will need to use the Xamarin.Forms 4.5-pre1 preview release. I understand that this might not be an option for all of you, but rest assured, the stable package will be out well before the deadline. Stable 4.5 is planned mid to end of February.
>
> Lastly, put the `--optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type` flag into your iOS additional mtouch arguments setting and you should get rid of the deprecation warning by Apple. If you don't have any references of your own to UIWebView of course
>
> I would like to ask you to try this at your earliest convenience. Maybe not to release an actual new version to the store based on the Forms preview package, but at least upload a build to verify that this solution works correctly. Whenever you do, you can just update to the 4.5 stable package and release a new version with confidence.
>
> If you do run into anything with this solution, please feel free to reach out to me directly (gerald.versluis [a with a long tail] microsoft.com) or open a new issue on the repository. Of course positive feedback is always appreciated as well